# Input from keyboard is throwing type error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to do the most basic thing which is trying to read from keyboard through input funtion.

I tried looking at other solutions in other links provided. But that doesnot helpme. As those are the ones where input was previously declared.
It is throwing me error :-

```
  File "<ipython-input-169-5d707bffda8e>", line 1, in <module>
    a = input("Enter the number")

TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not callable
```

I tried using 'input' to take the inputs from keyboard

```
a = input("Enter the number")


TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not callable
```

Comment: you seem to have overwritten `input` with something...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: '\_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not callable, creating text file error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33421209/typeerror-io-textiowrapper-object-is-not-callable-creating-text-file-error)

Comment: I am using python 3.x version. input is not being used anywhere else in the code. 'a' is not a file

Comment: Can you put a `print(input)` right before the line that produces the error and post what it prints out? It would also be much much easier to help you if you posted your entire code, not just a single line.

Comment: @Boris - When I tried print(input). It gave me the following:-print(input)
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='sample.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a line like

```
with open('sample.txt') as input:
```

in your code somewhere, which means that you've overwritten the builtin `input` function.

On that `with open` line (and any line where you use `input` as a file object like `for line in input:`) you need to change `input` to some other variable name, like `infile` or just `f`.

Comment: The code doesn't have with `open('sample.txt') as input:` . But looks like th e Ipython console had the variable input stored and it did not work there because of the same reason. When I restarted, it worked

Comment: @Aditya I don't think ipython redefines `input`. Do you mean you executed some code that overwrote `input`? You could fire up another ipython session and show us the output of `%history -g -f ipython_history.txt`. Unless you executed a script in interactive mode or did a global import from a local library that had a line like that, there's a good chance you'd find that line in your history.